# An enumeration problem for Dyck paths from homological algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

In their article "On n-Gorenstein rings and Auslander rings of low injective dimension" Fuller and Iwanaga gave a homological characterisation of 2-Gorenstein Nakayama algebras with global dimension at most three, see theorem 3.16. there. Now Nakayama algebras (we always assume they are acyclic) are in natural bijection to Dyck paths. Call a Dyck path nice in case the corresponding Nakayama algebra is 2-Gorenstein with global dimension at most 3, see below for an elementary combinatoria description. I noticed with the computer that nice Dyck paths seem to be enumerated by $2^{n-2}$ (thats why I call them nice) and the subclass of nice Dyck paths with global dimension at most two by the Fibonacci numbers. This leads to the following question:

> Question 1: Is there is a bijective proof mapping nice Dyck paths to some known/nice combinatorial objects?

Furthermore, to every nice Dyck path there is associated a canonical bijection and I wonder what this bijection is (there is a motivation to call this bijection homological rowmotion as it generalises the classical rowmotion from certain posets to more general combinatorial objects such as certain Dyck paths).

> Question 2: What is the associated bijection to a nice Dyck path?

I currently have no elementary description so question 2, is more of a guess from the data what it might be.

An $n$-*Kupisch series* (which we can identify with a Dyck path via its area sequence) is a list of $n$ numbers $c:=[c_1,c_2,...,c_n]$ with $c_n=1$, $c_i \ge 2$ for $i \neq n$ and $c_i-1 \leq c_{i+1}$ for all $i=1,...,n-1$ and setting $c_0:=c_n$.
The number of such $n$-Kupisch series is equal to $C_{n-1}$ (Catalan numbers).

Here are some examples of the nice Dyck paths for small $n$ together with the bijection on $\{1,..,n\}$.

$n=2$:

```
   [ [ 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ] ] ]
```

$n=3$:

```
  [ [ 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ] ], 

  [ [ 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ] ] ]
```

n=4:

```
   [ [ 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 4, 3 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 3 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 2 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 1 ] ]
```

n=5:

```
   [ [ [ 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 5, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 5, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 4, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 3 ] ] ],

   [ [ 3, 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 3 ] ] ],

   [ [ 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 5, 3 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 2 ] ] ],

   [ [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 1 ] ] ]
```

n=6:

```
   [ [ 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 6, 5 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 6, 5 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 4, 6 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 5 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 6 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 5 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 6 ], [ 5, 2 ], [ 6, 5 ] ] ],

   [ [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 6 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 6, 5 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 4 ] ] ], 

   [ [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 4 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 3 ] ] ],

   [ [ 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 3 ] ] ],

   [ [ 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 3 ] ] ],

   [ [ 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 2 ] ] ],

   [ [ 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ] ] ] ]
```

In the following I give the elemenatary combinatorial description of nice Dyck paths. Sadly, it is quite complicated at the moment despite the possibly very nice enumeration.

I found the following combinatorial characterisation of those Dyck paths (compare with [Combinatorics problem related to Motzkin numbers with prize money I](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278284/combinatorics-problem-related-to-motzkin-numbers-with-prize-money-i) ):

The *CoKupisch series* $d$ of $c$ is defined as $d=[d_1,d_2,...,d_n]$ with $d_i:= \min \{k | k \geq c_{i-k} \} $ and $d_1=1$. One can show that the $d_i$ are a permutation of the $c_i$. A number $a \in \{1,...,n \}$ is a *descent* if $a=1$ or $c_a >c_{a-1}$. Define a corresponding set, indexed by descents: $X_1 := \{1,2,...,c_1-1 \}$, and $X_a := \{ c_{a-1}, c_{a-1}+1  ,..., c_a -1 \}$ for descents $a > 1$.

A $n$-Kupisch series is called $2-$Gorenstein if it satisfies the following condition:

> 1. condition: for each descent $a$, and each $b \in X_a$:
>    either $c_{a+b} \geq c_{a+b-1}$ or $d_{a+b-1} = d_{a+b + c_{a+b}-1} - c_{a+b}$ is satisfied.

Now an $n$-Kupisch path is nice if and only if it is 2-Gorenstein and it has global dimension at most 3. Sadly there is no nice formal description of global dimension at most 3 but it can be pictured in a nice way in a Dyck path.

Call an $i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ good in case one of the following three conditions hold:

- $c_{i+1}=c_i -1$ (equivalent to the simple module $S_i$ having projective dimension one)
- ($c_{i+1}>c_i-1 $ and $c_{i+c_i}=c_{i+1}-c_i+1$) (equivalent to $S_i$ having projective dimension two)
- ($c_{i+1}>c_i-1 $ and $c_{i+c_i}>c_{i+1}-c_i+1$ and $c_{i+c_{i+1}+1}=c_{i+c_i}-c_{i+1}+c_i-1$) (equivalent to $S_i$ having projective dimension three)

Now the 2. condition is:

> 2. condition: Every $i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ is good.

So an n-Kupisch series (=Dyck path) is nice if and only if it satisfies condition 1. and 2.

Comment: Restricted to nice Dyck paths, http://www.findstat.org/St000386 and http://www.findstat.org/St000291 seem to have the same distribution.  The positions do not seem to be related in an easy way.

Comment: (a futher, less straightforward equidistribution is apparently https://www.findstat.org/St001036 and http://www.findstat.org/St000691.  This equidistribution appears to hold jointly with the other one.)

Comment: Possibly it is a better idea to first apply http://www.findstat.org//Mp00120.  We then get the joint equidistribution of http://www.findstat.org/St000011 and http://www.findstat.org/St000026 with http://www.findstat.org/St000288 (+1) and http://www.findstat.org/St000326, which might be doable.

Answer (score 4):

This is a conjectural answer.

Let $w = 0\dots01$ be a binary word of length $n$.  Then $\phi(w)$ is the Dyck path $U^{(n+1)/2} (UD)^{(n-1)/2} D^{(n+1)/2}$ if $n$ is odd and $U^{n/2} (UD)^{n/2} D^{n/2}$ if $n$ is even.

Let $w = 0^{n_1} 1 0^{n_2} 1 \dots 0^{n_k} 1$ be any binary word ending with a $1$.  Then $\phi(w) = \phi(0^{n_1} 1) \phi(0^{n_2} 1)\dots \phi(0^{n_k} 1)$.

Finally, to obtain the nice Dyck path, apply the Lalanne-Kreweras involution https://www.findstat.org//Mp00120.

Comment: I don't know what to make of all these answers by FindStat, but I think the correct link for this answer is http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00120

Comment: @DavidWhite Thank you for noticing it! The initial link did not work, I changed it and checked, but now my version does not work either, don't know why.

Comment: Seems to work now

Comment: @DavidWhite there should be a redirect, for me both versions work.  I use the shorter version, because it is shorter.  Concerning "FindStat answers": I like to post answers under this name if my scripts find the answer essentially automatically.

Comment: @MartinRubey, I think the issue is that the other user edited to change your // to / in the URL. Also, I didn't mean to be accusatory about the FindStat user, but at first glance I thought it odd to see so many links to the same domain. Instead of flagging as spam, I followed one and learned about your project, which seemed legit. I leave it to the experts to decide if it answers the present question.

Comment: @DavidWhite OK, makes sense, although I am surprised that the first instinct might be "spam".  Well, (part of) the idea is to tag statistics with findstat identifiers, very much in the same way as we tag sequences with oeis identifiers.